# Multiple Django Site Setup with Nginx & Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I need multiple Django projects run on my server. I tried [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756934/running-multiple-sites-with-djangos-sites-framework-through-gunicorn-nginx) after I tried running Gunicorn on different ports (8000/8001) on my own. I'm assuming it didn't work because my Django projects are in separate Virtual Environments.

To run start Gunicorn I ran `manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000` and `manage.py run_gunicorn 0.0.0.0:8001` in the different Virtual Enivronments.

After running the second Gunicorn deamon on port 8001 and adding the V-Host in Nginx for my second domain, opening the URL in my browser opened the first website. I rebooted my server and tried just running Gunicorn on port 8001 for the second site, and then I got a 502 error from Nginx, so I'm assuming the problem is Nginx related.

## Nginx V-Hosts

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name domain.me;
    # no security problem here, since / is alway passed to upstream
    root /opt/it/it/;
    # serve directly - analogous for static/staticfiles
    location /admin/static/admin/ {
        alias /opt/oloty/static/admin/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 10;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/;
    }
    location /static {    
        autoindex on;    
        alias /opt/oloty/static/;    
    }
    # what to serve if upstream is not available or crashes
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /media/50x.html;
}


server {
    listen   80;
    server_name domain.net;
    # no security problem here, since / is alway passed to upstream
    root /opt/it/it/;
    # serve directly - analogous for static/staticfiles
    location /admin/static/admin/ {
        alias /opt/it/static/admin/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 10;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    }
    location /static {    
        autoindex on;    
        alias /opt/it/static/;    
    }
    # what to serve if upstream is not available or crashes
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /media/50x.html;
}
```

## Django Settings

```
"""
Django settings for it project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'gunicorn',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/opt/it/templates/',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'it.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'it.wsgi.application'

SITE_ID = 1

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {

    }
}

##Logging

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Detroit'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "/opt/it/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/",
)

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/opt/it/static'


"""
Django settings for oloty project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'gunicorn',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/opt/it/templates/',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'oloty.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'oloty.wsgi.application'

SITE_ID = 2

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {

    }
}

#Logging

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Detroit'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/opt/oloty/static'
```

Comment: You received 502 error since nginx cannot access gunicorn via the proxy settings it has been provided. When you say you "got this error", which host did you attempt to access `domain.net` or `domain.me`?

Comment: domain.me, although I get the 502 for both.